# How do I change the audio output device from the command line in Raspbian?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to change output device from AV Jack to the bluetooth speaker. I can do that in GUI as attached in the picture but can't understand how to do the equivalent thing from the terminal. I tried using `amixer` but none of the commands seemed to do what I intended to.

[image: Changing sound device from AV Jack to Tronsmart]

Answer (score 1):

I've found this to work, type this into the terminal:

`sudo amixer cset numid=3 n`

where *n* is 0=auto, 1=headphones, 2=hdmi.

Im not sure if this is what you mean but I hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

I'm interested to know the answer to this too.

@Thomas's answer does not directly answer OP's question. That solution as stated in his answer, is for headphones and hdmi only.

OP is asking about setting the audio source output to Bluetooth Speaker via Command line.

I have tried many ways but to no avail. Unfortunately, it looks like there is no solution to setting via command line, except through desktop menu GUI, I think.

Comment: This can better be submitted as a "Comment" to the previous "Answer". And if you are suggesting a temporary change, your actual answer could only be that with "temporary solution" statement somewhere.